# Leitura e Recuperação de Dados Xml

Tags: c#, xml

Estou com a seguinte questão...

Estou fazendo a leitura de um Xml, e para pegar os valores dos nós eu uso ...

```
public class Produto {

    [XmlElement("PRODUTO")]
    public string produto;

}
```

Gostaria de uma forma de introduzir o nome do elemento **"PRODUTO"** de uma forma dinâmica, ou seja, pudesse mudar o nome do elemento.

- Exemplo:

```
string parametro = "produto";
XmlElement("parametro")]
public string produto;
```

Obs: Lembrando que a string produto vai receber o valor que for recuperado do elemento do XML.

Não sei se deu pra entender, mas espere que sim.

Comment: Não consegui entender, consegue exemplificar oque deseja fazer? Qual o objetivo? Você quer que a propriedade parametro aponte para a propriedade produto? É isso?

Comment: Eu tenho o XML de uma NFe, e preciso obter os dados dessa NFe recuperando atravéz da leitura do XML. Atualmente eu recupero os dados do XML utilizando. XmlElement e passo o nome da tag para recuperar o valor. Porém nem sempre o no e da TAG é o mesmo, então eu não posso utilizar dessa forma pq quando o nome da TAG for diferente do que está referênciado no código, vai dar erro, então eu queria uma forma de definir dinâmicamente o nome da tag para passar como parâmetro pro XmlElement, pra que dessa forma as tags sempre estivessem corretas.

Comment: E no caso eu usei o exemplo produto, mas na realidade eu preciso recuperar o valor do ICMS, mas como existem 33 códigos de ICMS fica complicado se não for dinâmico.